# With SonataAdminBundle. Configure filter on a two step related entity

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'd like to know weather is possible and how to configure a filter for the list view as the following with SonataAdminBundle in Symfony 2

Say I have entities Order, pointing to entities User, pointing to entities Company.
I want to configure filters both for filtering by User and also for filtering by Company (User's Company)
The first is straight forward. The second is what I try to clearify.

In the class OrderAdmin I would overwrite configureDatagridFilters as:

```php
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
     $datagridMapper
         ->add('created_at')
         //... some other filters on Order fields, as usual

         // the filter on User, provided 'user', no ploblem
         ->add('user')

         // and the filter by Company 
         ->add('user.company') // this doesn't work, of course
    ;
}
```

That syntax for the company filter is inpired by sonta docs: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/2-0/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html

Is not intended for what I try to acomplish, but cannot find where to look at.

Hope someone has a clue on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally I found an answer guided by this other question: [How can I create a custom DataGrid filter in SonataAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224280/how-can-i-create-a-custom-datagrid-filter-in-sonataadmin) and a closer read of the sonata admin docs link I pasted in my question.

In case someone have this issue and taking the previous example:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
   $datagridMapper

      //... whatever filter

      // and the filter by Company 

      ->add('company', 'doctrine_orm_callback', array(
            'callback'   => array($this, 'callbackFilterCompany'),
            'field_type' => 'checkbox'
            ),
    'choice', 
    array('choices' => $this -> getCompanyChoices())
;
}
```

where the method getCompanyChoices retrieves an associative array of company ids => company names (for instance). And the method callbackFilterCompany is as follows

```
public function callbackFilterCompany ($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value)
{
    if(!is_array($value) or !array_key_exists('value', $value) 
        or empty($value['value'])){

        return;

    }

    $queryBuilder
    ->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.user', $alias), 'u')
    ->leftJoin('u.company', 'c')
    ->andWhere('c.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', $value['value'])
    ;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This helped me with a minor change: instead of empty($value['value']) I would prefer is_null($value['value']) because empty(int(0)) is evaluated to true. Thanks a lot for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is well documented on the official website : http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html

Comment: yeah, I guess that in nov 2012 that was not the case yet ;-)

Comment: but it is now, so why downvote it.. it's still a correct relevant answer

Comment: This is why it is always recommended to adding an extract of the docs, and not just the link. That link is no longer working in 2023 :)